# Spark.sql usage with Google BigQuery in pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, google-cloud-platform, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, google-bigquery

I am in the process of migrating the Hadoop spark jobs to GCP.

I am blocked to migrate the statements with spark.sql to access the bigQuery tables. Because it is not working the sql queries and giving table/view not found error.

Ex: `df=spark.sql("select a.* from tableA a left join tableB b where a.id=b.id")`

I know that `spark.read.format('bigquery').option('table', 'project.database.table').load()`
to load the bigquery table to dataframe. but with read statement I need to create multiple dataframes and then join.

I feel it is simple with spark.sql in pyspark.

Can you please tell me how it is possible with spark.sql to process the sql queries?
or suggest the best way proceed without 'spark.read'.

Comment: if my answer is working could you please upvote the answer as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass your query to `dbtable` option like below

```
src_query = "(select a.* from tableA a left join tableB b where a.id=b.id)"

df = spark.read \
.format("bigquery") \
.option("url", "{}".format(src_host)) \
.option("dbtable", "{}".format(src_query)) \
.option("user", "{}".format(src_username)) \
.option("password", "{}".format(src_password)) \
.load()
```